# How I will "activate" the method in the server?

Tags: java, android, client

I am creating a turn based card game with a server in really basic level just to understand how things work.

It's a java android game and it's connected with a TCP into a Java server.

My problem is this:

I have a button into the client that has to roll a die into the server. I have a button listener like this

```
mRollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // WHAT I AM SENDING FROM HERE

        }
    });
```

but I am not sure what I have to send to server to "activate" the roll method when let's say that it is

```
public static int randomRoll() {
    return (int) (1 + Math.random() * 6);
}
```

Really new to this kind of programming.

Comment: I'm not so sure on android but maybe look into servlets

Comment: You can make an http request and use servlets, for example. You can check one of the examples online, such as: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Answer (score 0):

You could expose all the API methods as REST service on your server.
Then you would just call these URLs from listener to get the response back.